# Pagespeed with error: Lighthouse returned error: NO FCP

Tags: google-chrome, pagespeed

I am testing page speed with web sites:

- https://lolligroup.com
- https://ibneditore.it

This is the first time I receive the error:
(I have restarted PageSpeed many times, deleted cookies, cache..)

Lighthouse returned error: NO_FCP. Something went wrong with the recording
the trace over your page load. Please run the Lighthouse again. (NO_FCP)
(NO_FCP)

How to fix it?